# Creating a new button in Excel 2010 - howto link to code? Old ways seem prohibited

Tags: excel, vba, button, hyperlink

I want my EXCEL VBA code to create a new sheet, put some stuff on it, and put a button on the sheet linked to some code I've written.  I've used Google, and found several pages describing how to programatically create a button and link it to code.  However, all the pages I've found use something like 'With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveSheet.CodeName).CodeModule" to insert code.

Excel 2010 objects to this, issuing a protective message: Run-time error '1004': Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted.

How can I get around this?

Is there some other way I can link the button (which code created, just fine) to a sub I created?  I tried creating a Public Sub with the name suggested by the sample code I've found (name_Click()), but the sub never gets called.

Answer (score 1):

That message has actually been around since XL 2003.  You can make it go away by clicking on the Developer Tab, choosing Macro Security>Macro Settings and checking "Trust Access to the VBA project object model."

Obviously, this won't help you if you're distributing the workbook to others, but if it's just for you it will solve your problem.